# Installing Apache FOP library in Windows Shared Host

Tags: asp.net-mvc, apache, shared-hosting, apache-fop

I am interested in using Apache FOP to generate PDFs from XML within a website developed in ASP.NET.

My website is deployed in a shared Windows Host (reliablesite.net).  Is it possible to install Apache FOP in a shared windows host?

If you can provide a shared hosting service that provides that feature, please share it as well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there is no way to do this.

I ended up using [ITextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) for PDF functionality for an application hosted in a shared service.